# Lattices in $SL(n,\mathbb R)$

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, lattices, rt.representation-theory

If $\Gamma\subseteq SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is a lattice (i.e. discrete and finite covolume), does $\Gamma$ necessarily contain some $\mathbb{R}$-diagonalizable copy of $\mathbb{Z}^{n-1}$?

I know that the answer is yes if the lattice is cocompact, and that the answer is also yes in the case $\Gamma=SL(n,\mathbb Z)$.  So I wonder if every lattice satisfies this property.

Comment: What exactly does your second sentence mean???

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer.  Hopefully I didn't change what the OP is asking.

Comment: Ah, much better!

Comment: That is what I meant, thanks for the correction.

Comment: @ALB: I am curious as to why the proof is easier for uniform lattices?!

Comment: Isn't this one of the PCMI homework questions?

Comment: @agol what is pcmi?

Comment: @Agol: If you are talking about the question for uniform lattices, yes it is!

Comment: @ Igor Rivin: If $\Gamma$ is a uniform lattice in G and $\gamma$ is an element of $\Gamma$, then if H denotes the stabilizer of $\gamma$ in G, we have that $\gamma \cup H$ remains a lattice in H. Then apply this with $G = SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ and $\gamma$ an element of $\Gamma$ with n distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: I meant $\Gamma \cap H$ of course.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is yes. It is theorem [2.13] of the following paper of Prasad and Raghunathan:

Prasad, Gopal; Raghunathan, M. S. Cartan subgroups and lattices in semi-simple groups. Ann. of Math. (2) 96 (1972), 296–317.

There is also a lot of information in this paper:
http://www.math.bgu.ac.il/~barakw/papers/clorbit.pdf

Note that diagonalizable copies of $\mathbb{Z}^{n-1}$ in $\Gamma$ correspond to closed orbits for the action of the full diagonal subgroup of $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ on $SL(n,\mathbb{R})/\Gamma$.

This is related to the Margulis conjecture which (with some caveats) states that the closure of any orbit of the full diagonal on $SL(n,\mathbb{R})/\Gamma$ is algebraic, i.e. is itself the closed orbit of some subgroup. This conjecture is the biggest open problem in homogeneous dynamics (and in particular implies the Littlewood conjecture in number theory).

Comment: The link to the paper is dead, but, it should be available [here](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~barakw/papers/clorbit.pdf).

Answer (score 8):

This is a theorem of G. Prasad and M.S. Raghunathan. See Theorem 7.2 in [this paper of Steve Hurder's](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5188175/hurder.pdf) (rigidity of Anosov actions) -- the original reference is a bit less friendly.

Comment: @Alex Eskin and Igor Rivin: Ok, thank you for your precise answers and additionnal information.